# qCarousel Quasar Framework

Tags: quasar-framework

Хочу сделать слайдер как показано на скриншоте, вся проблема заключается в том, что я не могу найти подходящие иконки для контроллеров[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пересмотрела кучу стандартных иконок разных сервисов и везде они выглядят примерно следующим образом:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не хотелось бы рисовать отдельно иконки. Что делать?

Answer (score 0):

Например, 'horizontal_rule rounded' из набора Material Icons: https://fonts.google.com/icons?selected=Material%20Icons%3Ahorizontal_rule%3A